# how to get html elements created with an ngfor loop

Tags: angular, ngfor

Hello everyone here is a simplification of my problem

I created elements in my template using *ngfor

```
<table >
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let item of array" > {{item}}</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

 </table>
```

in the .ts file I have the table

```
array = [1,2,3,4];
```

and then when I try to display the elements in the console

```
  var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('th'); //or getElementById or anything..
  console.log(cells[1]);
```

it displays
**undefined**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Angular, You could take different approach.

**1)** Give some reference `#theadEl` to `th` element like,

```
<th *ngFor="let item of array" #theadEl> {{item}}</th>
```

**2)** Then in `ts` file make some imports from `@angular/core` like,

```
import { Component, ViewChildren, ElementRef, QueryList,
  AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
```

**3)** You need to use [**viewChildren**](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) along with [**QueryList**](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList) if we are trying to get multiple elements like,

```
 @ViewChildren('theadEl') theadEl: QueryList<ElementRef>
```

**4)** Then in [**ngAfterViewInit**](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) life cycle hook, you can achieve the result by using,

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const cells = this.theadEl.toArray();
    console.log(cells[1].nativeElement);
    console.log(cells[1].nativeElement.innerHTML);
  }
```

Finally,

**component.html**

```
<table >
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let item of array" #theadEl> {{item}}</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
 </table>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChildren, ElementRef, QueryList,
  AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 4';

  array = [1,2,3,4];

  @ViewChildren('theadEl') theadEl: QueryList<ElementRef>


  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const cells = this.theadEl.toArray();
    console.log(cells[1].nativeElement);
    console.log(cells[1].nativeElement.innerHTML);
  }

}
```

> [**Working Stackblitz Here...**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-example-42uu5x)

**Note:** The above is the best practice of usage but still if you want to use the same method of `document.getElementsByTagName('th');` , then you need to make the code into `ngAfterViewInit` life cycle hook as like below example.

[**Stackblitz with document.getElementsByTagName('th') method**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-example-8h2yeq)

Reason for using `ngAfterViewInit` is, it fully initialize a component's view.

Comment: worked for me on angular 8, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use it, `document.getElementsByTagName('th');` also works in Angular. The example should work fine and `console.log(cells[1]);` print the following to the console.

```
<th _ngcontent-c0> 2</th>
```

If in your case it results in `undefined`, the `table` may not have been created yet at the time when you invoke the command. I can think of the following two reasons that may be causing this.

1. The `table` is contained in an element that is currently not included in the document due an [`*ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) that results to `false`.
2. The command is invoked in the constructor at a point when the `table` has not been created in the [lifecycle sequence](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence).